# Idiomatic batch processing of text in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp

In Python, you might do something like

```
fout = open('out','w')
fin = open('in')
for line in fin:
    fout.write(process(line)+"\n")
fin.close()
fout.close()
```

(I think it would be similar in many other languages as well).
In Emacs Lisp, would you do something like

```
(find-file 'out')
(setq fout (current-buffer)
(find-file 'in')
(setq fin (current-buffer)
(while moreLines
 (setq begin (point))
 (move-end-of-line 1)
 (setq line (buffer-substring-no-properties begin (point))
 ;; maybe
 (print (process line) fout)
 ;; or
 (save-excursion 
  (set-buffer fout)
  (insert (process line)))
 (setq moreLines (= 0 (forward-line 1))))
(kill-buffer fin)
(kill-buffer fout)
```

which I got inspiration (and code) from *[Emacs Lisp: Process a File line-by-line](http://xahlee.info/emacs/emacs/elisp_process_lines.html)*. Or should I try something entirely different? And how to remove the `""` from the print statement?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you actually want batch processing of `stdin` and sending the result to `stdout`, you can use the [--script](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html#Initial-Options) command line option to Emacs, which will enable you to write code that reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout` and `stderr`.

Here is an example program which is like [`cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29), except that it reverses each line:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/emacs --script
;;-*- mode: emacs-lisp;-*-

(defun process (string)
  "just reverse the string"
  (concat (nreverse (string-to-list string))))

(condition-case nil
    (let (line)
      ;; commented out b/c not relevant for `cat`, but potentially useful
      ;; (princ "argv is ")
      ;; (princ argv)
      ;; (princ "\n")
      ;; (princ "command-line-args is" )
      ;; (princ command-line-args)
      ;; (princ "\n")

      (while (setq line (read-from-minibuffer ""))
        (princ (process line))
        (princ "\n")))
  (error nil))
```

Now, if you had a file named `stuff.txt` which contained

```
abcd
1234
xyz
```

And you invoked the shell script written above like so (assuming it is named `rcat`):

```
rcat < stuff.txt
```

you will see the following printed to stdout:

```
dcba
4321
zyx
```

So, contrary to popular belief, you can actually do batch file processing on `stdin` and not actually have to read the entire file in at once.

Comment: Cross-referencing to the following answer which shows how to pass additional command-line arguments to Emacs scripts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238331/emacs-shell-scripts-how-to-put-initial-options-into-the-script#6259330

Comment: Instead of `(condition-case ...)`, you could use `(ignore-errors ...)`, which does the same thing. Even better, remove the use of `condition-case` and replace `(read-from-minibuffer "")` with `(ignore-errors (read-from-minibuffer ""))`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I came up with.  Looks a lot more idiomatic to me:

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (let ((dest-buffer (current-buffer)))
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert-file-contents "/path/to/source/file")
      (while (search-forward-regexp ".*\n\\|.+" nil t)
        (let ((line (match-string 0)))
          (with-current-buffer dest-buffer
            (insert (process line)))))))
  (write-file "/path/to/dest/file" nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

Emacs Lisp is not suitable for processing file-streams. The whole file must be read at once:

```
(defun my-line-fun (line)
  (concat "prefix: " line))

(let* ((in-file "in")
       (out-file "out")
       (lines (with-temp-buffer 
        (insert-file-contents in-file)
        (split-string (buffer-string)  "\n\r?"))))
  (with-temp-file out-file
    (mapconcat 'my-line-fun lines "\n")))
```

Comment: `split-string` without any arguments defaults to splitting on `split-string-default-separators`, which is `"[ \f\t\n\r\v]+"` by default. You probably want to pass `"[\n\r]+"` in explicitly as the second argument.

Comment: And technically, "Emacs Lisp is not suitable for processing file-streams" is not true; you could use a process filter, but it is much more complicated and reading the whole file at once is probably the easiest way to do things. If reading a stream (such as a network socket) is really needed, you would probably have to use a process filter (see the Elisp manual).

Comment: Thanks: fixed split-string usage.

Comment: Actually, you can process `stdin`.