# Emacs shell scripts - how to put initial options into the script?

Tags: shell, emacs, command-line-arguments, elisp

Inspired by Stack Overflow question [Idomatic batch processing of text in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879746/idomatic-batch-processing-of-text-in-emacs) I tried out an Emacs shell script with the following headline:

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
```

I put some Emacs Lisp code in it, and saved it as textfile rcat.

Since the --script option does not prevent the loading of the site-start file, I had a lot of

```
Loading /etc/emacs/site-start.d/20apel.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs23/site-start.d/35elib-startup.el (source)...
Loading /etc/emacs23/site-start.d/50auctex.el (source)...
```

messages in the Bash shell (stdout). I can prevent that by calling

```
rcat --no-site-file
```

or

```
rcat -Q
```

but not by changing the headline in the script:

```
 #!/usr/bin/emacs --script --no-site-file
```

Is there a way to pass additional options to Emacs inside such a script file instead of doing it later on the commandline?

Comment: If you're still reading, I'd suggest changing the Accepted answer here to Gilles'.  I think it's the best answer to the question.  I adopted it very quickly myself as "standard" boilerplate for any elisp script, so 10 years later it feels weird that my answer still has the green tick here :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could always change `#!/usr/bin/emacs` to something like `#!/home/thorsten/bin/emacs-no-site-file`, and set that up as:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/emacs --no-site-file "$@"
```

If this doesn't work for you, or if you wish your script to be portable, then see [Gilles' answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238331/emacs-shell-scripts-how-to-put-initial-options-into-the-script#6259330) for a more robust (and slightly funky :) approach.

Comment: That works, thanks. I always forget, that the solution for almost all problems in Computer Science is inserting one additional (abstraction) step in the middle ;)

Comment: Unfortunately not all unices accept chained interpreters (i.e. a script can't be the interpreter of another script).

Answer (score 40):

Many unix variants only allow a single argument to the program on the shebang line. Sad, but true. If you use `#!/usr/bin/env emacs` so as not to depend on the location of the `emacs` executable, you can't pass an argument at all.

[Chaining scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238331/emacs-shell-scripts-how-to-put-initial-options-into-the-script/6240904#6240904) is a possibility on some systems, but that too is not supported everywhere.

You can go the time-honored route of writing a polyglot script: a script that is both a shell script and an Emacs Lisp script (like Perl's [`if $running_under_some_shell`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-S*), for example). It sure looks hackish, but it works.

Elisp comments begin with `;`, which in the shell separates two commands. So we can use a `;` followed by a shell instruction to switch over to Emacs, with the actual Lisp code beginning on the next line. Most shells don't like an empty command though, so we need to find something that both the shell and Emacs treat as a no-op, to put before the `;`. The shell no-op command is `:`; you can write it `":"` as far as the shell is concerned, and Emacs parses that as a constant at top level which is also a no-op.

```
#! /bin/sh
":"; exec emacs --no-site-file --script "$0" -- "$@" # -*-emacs-lisp-*-
(print (+ 2 2))
```

Comment: +1. Fantastic sh trickery. By chance I was about to start doing some emacs scripting for sending my org-agenda via e-mail every day, and this is just perfect. Thanks! It has the slight annoying thing of outputting one empty line at the beginning, though :(

Comment: Great! Why is everybody so critical about hacking and hackers? Software Engineers probably wouldn't find a solution as creative as this one.

Comment: Cross-referencing to the following answer+comment, which shows how to incorporate the `--` argument into this approach to prevent Emacs from trying to process the command line arguments passed to your script http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759606/passing-arguments-to-elisp-script-again/6807133#6807133

Comment: @DiegoSevilla That empty line is from the `print` function, which prints a newline before and after the object. Use `prin1` or `princ` to avoid the newlines.

Comment: OK, I see... Thanks. Yes, with the time, I've been learning more of those lispses :)

Comment: It looks like a general solution still needs to `(setq argv nil)` before the script exits (as per Jurijs Oniscuks' answer), as Emacs will process any remaining arguments as filenames to be visited. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24352935/324105

Comment: Actually, even better than purging `argv` is to simply exit explicitly at the end of the script with `(kill-emacs 0)` (assuming `0` is the appropriate status at that point), which ensures (a) that Emacs doesn't do anything else (processing of remaining arguments, or otherwise); and (b) that you guarantee which exit status your script is returning (which is something you should want to do in any case). Refer to http://www.lunaryorn.com/2014/08/12/emacs-script-pitfalls.html

Comment: I'll also leave a link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/10211087/324105 which collects the key boiler-plate (IMO) for writing an elisp script, based on this and other Q&As.

Answer (score 9):

If you run emacs in script mode, I would recommend to reset "argv" variable to nil in the end of your script, otherwise emacs will try interpret "argv" after script is finished.

Let's assume you have a file named "test-emacs-script.el" with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script
(print argv)
(setq argv nil)
```

Try running this script as "./test-emacs-script.el -a". If you run this script without resettings "argv" (last line in the script) then the output will be:

```
("-a")
Unknown option `-a'
```

Resetting "argv" gets rid of "unknown option" error message

Comment: It looks like this is important even when the `--` argument is used, as lunaryorn [points out in another Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24352935/324105) that Emacs will still process non-option arguments as filenames, if any are present. Emptying `argv` prevents that.

Comment: Even better, if you `(kill-emacs 0)` to explicitly exit with the specified status, Emacs won't do *anything* else. This tip from http://www.lunaryorn.com/2014/08/12/emacs-script-pitfalls.html (which has become a pretty comprehensive overview, I think).