# Evaluate emacs lisp expression on command line

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacsclient

I'm a newbie to emacs. I'm working with emacs-24.1 on redhat linux, and trying to evaluate an elisp expression. What I want emacs to do is to evaluate the elisp expression without launching emacs itself. I'm trying different things

```
emacs --eval '(+ 2 3)'
```

I do not know if emacs is evaluating the expression, but the result is not shown on console and emacs window comes up. Next I tried this

```
emacsclient --eval '(+ 2 3)'
```

Emacs client is expecting a server. It could not find the server and hence throwing an error (can't find socket. start server etc). So I launched a server (server-name is SERVER) and ran emacsclient again

```
emacsclient --server-file=SERVER -e '(+ 2 3)'
```

This time, emacs evaluated the expression and printed the result on console. That is because emacs is using the existing server to evaluate the expression. Now I get a problem when the server is not running.

```
emacsclient --server-file=ANOTHER_SERVER -e '(+ 2 3)' -a emacs
```

This time, I'm not getting any error on console. Emacs is launching a new window, because of -a (my .emacs has (server-start) command in it and server-name set to ANOTHER_SERVER). But emacs then is trying to edit the file (+ 2 3). It is shown on the mode line. I'm confused. emacsclient --help showed me this

```
-e, --eval              Evaluate the FILE arguments as ELisp expressions
```

and emacs manual says this.

```
'-e'
'--eval'
Tell Emacs to evaluate some Emacs Lisp code, instead of visiting some files.
When this option is given, the arguments to emacsclient are interpreted as a
list of expressions to evaluate, not as a list of files to visit.
```

I do not know how to proceed on this. As I said, my goal is to evaluate an elisp expression without launching emacs. Is it possible?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210742/run-elisp-program-without-emacs (and its related links!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a bit of testing it looks like you can use `--batch` to have emacs dump any messages to stderr.  Then you can call `message` to print things to stderr where you'll be able to see them.  Your example would become `emacs --batch --eval '(message (number-to-string (+ 2 3)))'` and the result would be printed to stderr.

If you're trying to redirect the output to a file you'll need to redirect stderr instead of stdout by using `2>` instead of just `>`.

Comment: There may be a better way, I'm pretty new to emacs myself.

Comment: Why's this not working ?  emacs --batch --eval "(message (symbol-value 'user-init-file))"

Comment: Very rough guess but I'm going to assume the environment is a little different when emacs is run in batch mode so user-init-file may not be initialized as it normally would.  Are you sure you don't actually want something like `M-x ielm` in emacs rather than doing this on the command line?  You'd get a nice elisp REPL where you can play around instead.

Comment: However, interestingly (OSX/Emacs 24.1), you can apparently force loading an init file even in batch mode, i.e., this works: emacs -u keith --batch --eval "(print (symbol-value 'user-init-file))"  The -u user option will look for and load the specified user's init file (.emacs).

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
emacs --batch --eval '(print (+ 2 3))'
```

Comment: Thanks! Up-voted.

That command includes a newline preceding the output value. To avoid the newline:

`emacs --batch --eval '(message "%s" (+ 2 3))' 2>&1`

Comment: Another way to not have the prepended newline, but still have one appended (which I presume is desirable) would be: `emacs --batch --eval '(princ (format-message "%s\n" (+ 2 3)))'` ... and if you don't even care about the trailing newline, that can be shortened down to `emacs --batch --eval '(princ (+ 2 3))'`.  With either of these, you don't risk sending _actual errors_ into your output stream, as the `2&1` solution does.