# Scripting export of org-mode tables

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

Is there a way to export an `org-mode` table to a file without running the interactive `org-table-export` command from emacs?

I often use `org-mode` to create tables that I then export either to `latex` for inclusion in my main `latex` file or to csv for import into `R` for further processing.

I suspect that this could all be handled using a dynamic document that uses `org-babel`. But I find keeping `R` code and text separate and using `make` simpler, so would like way to export these tables programmatically so that I could make sure the latest version is updated before compiling my final text or running my `R` analysis.

So I'm looking for a way to run `org-table-export` on a specified file from the shell (that way I could put it in a makefile or in an `R` script).

I think I can run an `elisp` function from the command line using `--batch --eval` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11475245/1072349, but I don't know enough `elisp` to write the function to pass a file to `org-table-export`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking into org-table-export the following should work:

```
(defun my-export-batch-function (my-org-file pos-inside-my-table my-org-table-saved-file)
  (find-file my-org-file)
  (goto-char pos-inside-my-table)
  (org-table-export my-org-table-saved-file))
```

Remains the Emacs batch-mode part