# How to run emacs lisp interpreter in shell?

Tags: python, shell, emacs, elisp

I am trying to run some examples of programs in Emacs Lisp.

- How can we run its interpreter in shell, and then run some commands line by line with output immediately available? Is it similar to Python, for which we first type `python` to run its interpreter, and then type any commands inside it?
- how can we run such a program without we entering into its interpreter? Is it similar to Python, for which we can run `python myscript.py` in the shell?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Use the REPL inside Emacs: <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ielm` <kbd>RET</kbd>

I don't know if there's a shell-based REPL, but you could possibly *make* one without too much difficulty.

Consider:

```
$ emacs -Q --daemon=myrepl
$ emacsclient --socket-name=myrepl --eval '(princ user-emacs-directory)'
"~/.emacs.d/"
$ emacsclient --socket-name=myrepl --eval '(kill-emacs)'
```

(but really, just use `ielm`).

2) If you actually have shell scripts written in elisp, then take a look at this Q&A: [Run elisp program without Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210742/run-elisp-program-without-emacs)

But that's *not* a common thing to do, and there are lots of reasons not to write elisp scripts.

If you're unfamiliar with Emacs and simply have a `.el` file you don't know what to do with, this almost certainly isn't what you want to do. Elisp libraries are nearly always intended to be loaded inside of Emacs, rather than executed from the shell.

(If you're at all unsure, I recommend that you update your question with an example, as you're possibly asking the wrong questions.)