# Has anyone used elisp as a script language?

Tags: emacs, lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Idomatic batch processing of text in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879746/idomatic-batch-processing-of-text-in-emacs)

I really like eshell. 
I'm just wondering whether it could be used as a script language just as a `shell script`.