# GNU+Linux Build Framework in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: emacs, elisp, build-automation, linux-from-scratch

I'm working on a Linux-libre version of "Linux from Scratch" based upon Christophe Jarry's "GNU/Linux-libre from source code" build book.  However, rather than write a build framework with shell scripts or Perl, I'm actually interested in extending my Emacs Lisp chops.  Only having used Emacs Lisp within Emacs and Org-mode as an extension language, does anyone have some tips/tricks/or links to projects that have done something similar?  The reason it is important to me is that my end product will be a minimal GNU+Linux-libre system with an Emacs-centered interface, and this just would round out the project nicely.  TIA, and cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what the question is here, but if you want some help with writing executable elisp scripts, you might find these useful:

- [Emacs shell scripts - how to put initial options into the script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238331/emacs-shell-scripts-how-to-put-initial-options-into-the-script/6259330#6259330)
- [Idomatic batch processing of text in Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879746/idomatic-batch-processing-of-text-in-emacs/2906967#2906967)
- [Run elisp program without Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10210742/run-elisp-program-without-emacs/10211087#10211087)

Alternatively, you might look at using [guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), which supports elisp as a source language.

Comment: Thanks, @phils - I was actually looking for some specific project examples that implement a similar framework.  Writing it from scratch is fine, but to save some time I'd like to see what others have done.  Definitely, guile is an option, but my preference would be to make this an emacs mode with larger back-end functionality.  I'm only moderately skilled in elisp and guile, so the example as a jump-off will really help.  Cheers!